# Можно ли считать Electron.js полноценной технологией для создания десктопных приложений? Мобильных?

Tags: javascript, electron, мобильные-приложения

Не смог пока установить у себя инструменты для разработки `Electron.js`. Стоит ли она того? В основном одни рекламные тексты, сути нет.

1. Можно ли создавать полноценные приложения на Electron? Вроде CorelDraw, SolidWorks, хотя бы БазисМебельщик или bCAD? Имеет ли приложение доступ к системе? к видеокарте? Или это баловство и лучше изучать `С++` и `Qt`? (может другое)
2. Какими будут мобильные приложения? Это будут нативные или web приложения? В GoogleStore их можно будет разместить? Или без `JAVA` (Android Studio) и `Objective-C`|| `Swift` (Xcode) не обойтись?

---

Понимаю, вопрос нельзя считать однозначным, и прошу высказывать суждения, основанные на личном использовании и имеющейся у вас информации, а не найти ошибку в коде. Однозначного ответа нет, но общий вопрос звучит так:

**При имеющейся возможности изучить любую другую технологию для создания десктоп и мобильных приложений, стОит ли связываться с Electron.js?**

Comment: а разве Electron билдится в мобильные приложения?

Comment: Оказалось, что нет. Абсолютно.

Comment: И что Вы выбрали?

Comment: @Дмытрык, пока тыркаю Electron с прицелом на ReactNative или просто PWA для мобильных.

Comment: Для мобильных приложений наиболее передовой ныне технологией является Flutter гугловский. Не создаёт проблем, работая одинаково и под Android и под IOS, десктопки пока в бете, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да, я пробовал функционал 2 года назад и оказалось, что нет возможности для графики как `canvas` в HTML, может сейчас появилась поддержка? Что можно сделать с помощью Flutter? Данные о погоде показывать? Детскую игру можно сделать с минимальной анимацией, графикой, рисованием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VSCode**, **Slack**, **RaidCall** написаны c помощью `ELectron`, если для кого-то они являются авторитетом.

обобщая, такие технологии называются `WebView`, то есть, по сути, всё Ваше приложение на `Electron` - это просто страница браузера, которая "косит" под нативное приложение. это не хорошо и не плохо

Comment: Значит, вместо OpenGL(Vulkan) --> WebGL? А мобильные приложения в магазин можно выложить? Лицензия?

Comment: а х*р его знает **:D** всегда, когда дело доходило до мобильных приложений, то речь шла о `ReactNative` и т.д.. но, теоретически, это возможно

Comment: Спасибо за помощь